# Autowireing of Qualified Datasource not working

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I have a SpringBoot 2.0.4 app, and I am using JdbcTemplates.  I had it all working, when I got a requirement to do a data transfer between 2 DBs.

So I set up 2 Data Sources like this:

```
@Configuration 
public class OracleConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "oracleDataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oracle.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
}
```

and my DAO is like this:

```
@Repository
@Component
public class personDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CymNetworkDao.class);

@Autowired
public void setDs(@Qualifier("oracleDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
     setDataSource(dataSource);
}

public List<PersonBean> findAll() {
    List<PersonBean> result = getJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT * FROM PERSON", new PersonRowMapper());
    return result;
}
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; 
 nested exception is   
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
 No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: 
 expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
 {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=oracleJdbcTemplate)}
```

My reading of tutorials was telling me to just autowire the datasource, and the jdbcTemplate would create itself.  Am I qualifying wrong or something else?

Comment: no you should create `JdbcTemplate` with configuring `datasource` bean in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create `jdbcTemplate` by injecting `DataSource` like following example

```
@Repository
public class personDao {
private JdbcTemplate oracleJdbcTemplate;
@Autowired
public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("oracleDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    this.oracleJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

And in error message it clearly shows it was missing `JdbcTemplate` bean

```
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=oracleJdbcTemplate)}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that setting the datasource was enough to get the JdbcTemplate working.  But it's obvious now that I see it.  Thanks!